# Scrollbar in DIV

Tags: css

I need to display both the scrollbars if any one is displayed. Is there any way to do this

Now I am using the below one, which is just displaying in either one direction. I should not limit using Height or Max-Height property.

```
.AutoOverflow {
    overflow:auto; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`overflow: auto` ***will*** display both the scrollbars ***if*** required.

That is where your confusion lies. Without looking at your markup and other associated styles, it seems that the content does *not require* both the scroll bars and hence only the vertical one is displayed.

This is because, by default the content wraps unless it is explicitly told not to. Elements like `table` try to shrink-fit unless explicitly told not to. If you have a table content which exceeds the width, you will see the horizontal scrollbar as well. If you have contents that do not wrap, you will see the horizontal scrollbar.

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/4wWNU/4/***

*CSS*:

```
div {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    height: 100px; width: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}

div#d2, div#d3 {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div#d4 > table {
    width: 150%;
}
```

In the fiddle above, notice each `div`:

In the first, the content is simple text which by default wraps and hence only vertical scrollbar.

In second the contents are forced not to wrap by using a `white-space: nowrap;`, and you see only the horizontal scrollbar.

In third, the contents (text) are forced not to wrap but there are multiple `p` and hence once overflowed, you see both scrollbars.

In fourth, there is a table which exceeds the width of the container and hence you see both the scrollbars. Try removing the width on the table and you will see that the table tries to shrink-fit and hence only vertical scrollbars.

Comment: Yes. Vertical scrollbar is not required. But user wants to forcefully display it when horizontal scrollbar displayed.

Comment: @Gansun: Please see the fiddle again. Unfortunately, you don't have much options here. Your question is not very clear. What is the markup? What are the contents like? Under what circumstances are you getting a horizontal scrollbar? Based on that, which among the four examples best suits your scenario?

Comment: In the fiddle you have specified both height & width. In my scenario I have a fixed width but the height is auto. Updated the fiddle. That is my scenario. I need to have horizontal in d3 or d4

Comment: @Gansun: If height is auto, then the div will expand to accommodate the content. So, no, you can't place a vertical scrollbar.

Comment: @Gansun: You have `overflow: scroll;` but that will add both the scrollbars, required or not.

Comment: Initially I started with overflow: scroll; But the problem is scrollbar always displayed even if it's not required.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54799/discussion-between-gansun-and-abhitalks).

Comment: @Gansun: Yes, that's what I said. No, you can't do much about that using CSS only. You could using Javascript, but that would be an overkill.

Comment: Anyway Thanks. I will try to convince the users to live with Horizontal scroll bar.